# if/else performance difference depending on code location

Tags: performance

Say I have an if/else statement and also some code that should execute in either case. I can put the "common" code in each block, or I can put it after the statement, e.g.:

```
if (x)
{
    i++;
    k++;
    return;
}
else
{
    j++;
    k++;
    return;
}
```

or

```
if (x)
{
    i++;
}
else
{
    j++;
}
k++;
return;
```

Is there a difference in performance between the two methods? If so, which one is faster, and why?

Comment: It depends on the compiler and computer architecture. Some compilers may notice the common code and combine it automatically.

Comment: Is this routine a bottleneck in your program? If not, don't concern yourself with such micro-optimization. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Barmar No this is pseudocode, it's just a question I had in my mind and I have in the past written both ways and wondered if it made any difference.

Comment: A compiler might be able to do that, but the CPU won't do it by itself. A branch predictor that mispredicts would likely have to flush all the bogus code path, it can't keep the `k++` selectively (at least not on any CPU i've seen)

Comment: There's no general answer. You have to look at the generated code when you put it in a real program. The compiler may optimize it, there can be dependencies on things like cache hits and misses, etc.